# GAS: What counts as "service invoked"?

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail

When I run my script, I get an error saying "Exception: Service invoked too many times for one day: gmail".
I'm not sure which of the quotas mentioned on google's documentation is the relevant one, but more importantly - I'm not sure what counts as invoking the gmail service.
I use GmailApp.getUserLabelByName(), and store the label in a variable. I guess that counts, but then, does every action I perform on that label, or on a thread therein (e.g. addLabel()) count as invoking the service?

Comment: Were you sending email?